# Windows username fetch in PHP (computername coming)

Tags: php

i have this function below and works good but brings user of computer name

```
<?php echo getenv("USERNAME"); ?>
```

I want to bring name from windows like mazhar is windows user name which we usually see in strart

Thanks

I want to bring name from windows like mazhar is windows user name which we usually see in start but by command above i am getting computername so my question is different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read Windows logged in username with PHP/IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899643/how-to-read-windows-logged-in-username-with-php-iis)

Comment: No it is about network user which you are showing i am bringing windows user and my code is bringing computername which i dont need